# Ruby - Evaluate expressions while debugging in Netbeans

Tags: ruby, netbeans, ruby-1.9, ruby-debug

I am using Netbeans as a ruby IDE, When I'm debugging I would like to be able to run an expressions to see values or ouputs of method calls when I have hit a break point. Is this possible in netbeans, if so how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not available in the Netbeans IDE, there is an [enhancement request](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=107761)  but Netbeans have now dropped Ruby support.